# Different layouts in a viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-adapter, swipe-gesture

I am trying to do something like the android market to show products from different categories. I have implemented that behavior with [this](https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions) library, and it's all running good.

What I want to do now is to have a list view in the page of the categories, and in each one of the others a grid view. Of course, each one of them will have different sources of data.

How can I achieve that ? Does it have anything to do with adapters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want extend [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html), override `getItem`, and return the proper Fragment object (or ListFragment) depending on the index/position in the ViewPager.

In the layout xml for your Activity you should include a `ViewPager` (`<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>`), and in your Activity `onCreate` use the `setAdapter` method of `ViewPager` to assign your `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks. And when I return the proper Fragment, I should create a new one or do something like:

return MyFragment.newInstance(position);

Comment: Either would work. Depends how different the two fragments are - it might make sense to split them up into two different classes, or it might make sense to have a single fragment which changes based on what you pass to it's constructor. Personally, I'd go with two different Fragment classes.

Answer (score 9):

I have find one Very good Example you can find that on this site

https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions

Else hope this code will be Helpful to you.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    View v = new View(PatientView.this.getApplicationContext());
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) PatientView.this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patientp1,
                (ViewGroup) null, false);
        ((Button) v.findViewById(R.id.pp1btnbck)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        break;
    case 1:
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patientp2, null, false
                );
        break;
    default:

        TextView tv = new TextView(PatientView.this.context);
        tv.setText("Page " + position);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tv.setTextSize(30);
        v = tv;
        break;
    }
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(v, 0);

    return v;
}
```

Comment: buddy i am trying this but here i am getting error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from View to int " on  v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patientp1,
                (ViewGroup) null, false);